# How to open password protected AES 128 encrypted SQLite 3 database in java(eclipse)? take note NOT in android

Tags: java, sqlite

How to open password protected AES 128 encrypted SQLite 3 database in java(eclipse)? take note NOT in android...

Using any jar, libraries that can open the encrypted sqlite database.